# Android Market Developer Console Statistics

Tags: statistics, google-play

I would like to get some stats programmatically about my app; for example: total downloads, active installs...

I wish google would give an api for doing this. What do people do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There currently is no API, and it is possible to get these statistics, but it's quite complicated (you have to get an AuthSub token for the market developer service, and then do the right requests and parse a number of GWTRPC encoded responses. These GWTRPC responses change everytime they launch a new version of the android market dashboard, so be prepared to monitor frequently whether this has happened).

In a recent chat with one of the Android folks from Google I heard that they are aware of this issue and know that it's a very popular demand by developers, so hopefully there will be a better way soon.

Comment: yeah that's what I am doing and recently they changed the format and my script broke. I am launching a browser and stuff like that :)

Comment: Has there been any development on this?